# How to make dark mode of Tailwind CSS work with Next.js and styled-jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, styled-jsx

My site is built with Next.js and Tailwind CSS. I followed the [default instructions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs) to install them. Since I wanted to customize the appearance of my links without applying inline classes to each one, I also installed [`styled-jsx-plugin-postcss`](https://github.com/giuseppeg/styled-jsx-plugin-postcss) so that I could use `styled-jsx` [already bundled](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#css-in-js) in Next.js.

It worked almost perfectly, but for some reason the dark mode styles applied in the `<style jsx>` tag are ignored. I'm using the `class` strategy [as documented](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually). How can I make these styles work?

Below is a sample code from `index.js`. [I also uploaded it to Codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwindcss-stlyedjsx-nextjs-morb7?file=/pages/index.js)

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  const handleThemeChange = (newTheme) => {
    const bodyClasses = document.body.classList;
    newTheme === "dark" ? bodyClasses.add("dark") : bodyClasses.remove("dark");
    localStorage.theme = newTheme;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const defaultTheme =
      localStorage.theme ||
      (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches
        ? "dark"
        : "light");
    handleThemeChange(defaultTheme);
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) return null;

  return (
    <div className="dark:bg-black dark:text-white text-xl">
      <ul className="cursor-pointer mb-6">
        <li
          onClick={() => handleThemeChange("dark")}
          className="block dark:hidden"
        >
          Click to activate dark mode
        </li>
        <li
          onClick={() => handleThemeChange("light")}
          className="hidden dark:block"
        >
          Click to activate light mode
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p>
        <a href="#">This link</a> should be red in dark mode.
      </p>
      <style jsx>{`
        a {
          @apply text-green-500 dark:text-red-500;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think I came with a functional solution for now (see answer below), but it would be great if I could solve this without touching the code (if possible somehow).

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I realized that when the `dark:` variant is used inside `<style jsx>`, the `.dark` class generated in the final CSS is also scoped. So I have to do a workaround using the [one-off global selector `:global()`](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#one-off-global-selectors):

```
<style jsx>{`
  a {
    @apply text-green-500;
  }

  :global(.dark) a {
    @apply text-red-500;
  }
`}</style>
```

It demands slight code refactoring, but I'm afraid there's no way Tailwind could bypass scoping automatically (maybe it would even be an unexpected pattern if it did that?).