# TailwindCSS Dark mode inexplicable behavior

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I have been playing with TailwindCSS for a while now in a project using NextJS. I added a Dark Mode by following the officiel documentation but also articles I could find in the web.
I added also a toggle button to switch from light to dark mode. When enabled, one and only one tag works. In this instance this one:

```
const Background = () => {
  return (
    <div className="md:absolute inset-0 ">
      <div className="bg-gradient-to-b dark:from-black from-white to-gold-200 md:min-h-screen" />
    </div>
  );
};

export { Background };
```

Any other tries don't work. For instance I want to use light text on this background:

```
<nav className="f-f-l relative z-10">
  <div className="relative z-10 mx-auto container hidden w-full px-4 xl:px-0 lg:flex justify-between items-center py-11">
    <div>
      <img
        src={`${router.basePath}/pathtoimage`}
        width={300}
        alt="alt image"
      />
    </div>
    <div className="flex items-center text-lg font-bold text-gray-900  dark:text-white">
      <ul className="flex items-center pr-3 xl:pr-12 ">
        <li className="cursor-pointer hover:underline">
          <Link href="/">
            <a>Link1</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="pl-3 lg:pl-5 xl:pl-8 cursor-pointer hover:underline">
          <a>Link2</a>
        </li>
        <li className="pl-3 lg:pl-5 xl:pl-8 cursor-pointer hover:underline">
          <a>Link3</a>
        </li>
        <li className="pl-3 lg:pl-5 xl:pl-8 cursor-pointer hover:underline">
          <ModalClass />
        </li>
      </ul>
      <DarkModeToggle />
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

What am I doing wrong? The dark mode works perfectly for the Background class but not this  or any other tag or class for that matter.

Comment: If you inspect the DOM in the devtools, do you see the `dark:text-white` class being applied on the `div` element in dark mode? Could something be overriding it?

Comment: @juliomalves I can't see it. I did a little bit of research and I found this same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68115888/how-to-make-dark-mode-of-tailwind-css-work-with-next-js-and-styled-jsx . His solution works perfectly, but it is not a viable solution for my case since I have a relatively big project.